# How to close specific X11-windows from the shell?

Tags: unix, shell, xorg, shell-script, window

How can specific windows be closed from the command line, without killing their controlling application?

Question based on an example to make it clearer:

I recently had an application running havoc and opening many `firefox`-windows. I needed to close them, without terminating `firefox` (since this would just restore the windows via `firefox`'s session restoration). How can windows be "just closed" from the shell, like hitting the close-button?

Comment: Just `wmctrl -c firefox` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @PabloBianchi: Yes, I did not know about this `wmctrl`. You can make this a full answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simply

```
wmctrl -c firefox
```

From [`wmctrl` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl): Interact with a EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager.

- You can be more strict with `-F` option:

  > `-F` Window  name  arguments (`<WIN>`)  are to be treated as exact window titles that are case sensitive. Without this options window titles are considered to be case insensitive sub‐strings of the full window title.
- To kill a specific window you can list them with `wmctrl -l` and then close it with `wmctrl -ic ID`.

Not sure what would the approach on Wayland.

Also answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106377/349837).

Answer (score 2):

The combination of [`xlsw`](http://github.com/baskerville/xlsw) and [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) does the trick.

`xlsw` lists windows by their title and type, `xdotool` does actions on them. In principle, `xdotool` can also search for windows' names, but it missed what were popup windows.

In `bash`:

```
xlsw | grep 'Firefox/Popup' | awk '{print $1}' | \
  while read _windowID; do xdotool windowclose "${_windowID}"; done
```

Explanation:

`xlsw` outputs a list of window-IDs together with additional information. Output looks like:

```
[...]
0x04800001  u--  Pale moon/pale moon  Pale Moon
0x04800092  uio  NA           Pale Moon
0x04800093  u-o  Pale moon/palemoon  Pale Moon
0x04800099  u-o  Pale moon/palemoon  Pale Moon
0x04828D21  u-o  Pale moon/Popup  Pale Moon
0x0489C5D6  u-o  Pale moon/Popup  Pale Moon
0x03600001  ui-  NA           NA
0x04604E77  --o  Claws-mail/claws-mail  claws-mail
0x04604EAC  --o  Claws-mail/claws-mail  claws-mail
0x04604F22  --o  Claws-mail/claws-mail  claws-mail
0x05C00001  uio  NA           NA
0x05E00001  u--  NA           NA
0x05200007  ui-  NA           NA
0x05E00002  u--  Wine/explorer.exe  
[...]
```

Then, with the `grep`-command, the popup-windows of `firefox` will be selected (in the example above they are all gone, already). `awk` prints the first entry, which is the window-ID, and then `xdotool windowclose` will close the windows (something *like* hitting the close button) without killing it's controlling application. (`xdotool windowkill` would kill the application.)

`xdotool` has also a build in search: `xdotool search 'firefox' windowclose` would also close all windows with 'firefox' in their title, but I did not get it to work to differentiate the 'Popup'.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed on your profile that you are a user at Ask Ubuntu, so I will share the method that I use to select and close an open window from the shell on Ubuntu. The same method also works on many other Linux distrubtions.

- `wmctrl -mlpx` lists the open windows with the window IDs and a description of each window. For Firefox the description is the title of the tab that has the focus and pop-up windows are listed as separate windows.
- `wmctrl -ic <window-id>` closes a window that has id=`window-id` from the terminal.

If you don't have wmctrl installed, it can be installed with `sudo apt install wmctrl` in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu without requiring any other software from GitHub to be installed. There is also an .rpm of wmctrl in the Fedora package database.

Comment: On Arch Linux I also do not require to install from github. Just provided the upstream-URLs; I suspect the users are firm with their distributions's packaging system to search if it is available there.